# Why was Logan surprised to see Professor X and Storm in the end?

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past

At the end of X-Men:Days of Future Past, why did Logan act surprised to  see Storm and Professor X, whom he had no clue were dead. The others, Beast, Cyclops, Jean Grey, I understand his surprise to see them, but why was surprised to see people who were still alive as far as he remembered?

Comment: Logan doesn't seem to be especially surprised to see Storm, so much as surprised to see that **everything has changed**. He's wandering around in a daze for much of that scene like he's drunk/dazed

Comment: Could be, I just watched it though, he didn't seem to surprised to see Iceman or Rogue, whom when he left them they were alive. He was definately in a daze for the  scene because of the circumstances, but it seems like he surprised to see some more than others. Maybe I'm reading too much into it.

Comment: He'd been switching between McAvoy and Stewart through the movie, and the timelines are so confusing.

Answer (score 4):

I would say it was because when he woke up, he didn't know what to expect. True, he knew that stopping Mystique from murdering Trask in 1973 would prevent the horrific things he and the X-Men had to endure during the war with the Sentinels, but as he leaves his room, it should be noted that he's not quite sure what has happened due to his tampering with the timeline. Therefore, his shock of seeing Rogue and Iceman alive, and still a couple, and seeing Beast alive when he shouldn't have been and still teaching at the school (Remember, in X3, Beast didn't stay with the X-Men) is very understandable. As for his shock of seeing Kitty, Colossus, and Storm, it appears to be relief that they are still alive. This is very vaguely hinted at when he sees Jean, who he personally killed in the original timeline, in this scene:

> **LOGAN**: Jean? You're here?
>   **JEAN**: Where else would I be? (Pause) Is everything all right?
>   **LOGAN**: Yeah. Yeah, I think it will be.

As for Professor X, Logan is not so shocked that the Professor is alive as he is that he (he being Logan, not the Professor) is this timeline's History teacher, as shown in this scene:

> **PROFESSOR X**: Logan, don't you have a class to teach?
>   **LOGAN**: A class...to teach?
>   **PROFESSOR X**: History.
>   **LOGAN**: History? Actually, I could use some help with that.
>   **PROFESSOR X**: Help with what?
>   **LOGAN**: Well, pretty much everything after about 1973. I think the history I know is a little different.
>   **PROFESSOR X** (whispers): Welcome back.
>   **LOGAN**: It's good to see you, Charles; it's good to see everyone.
>   **PROFESSOR X**: Well, I had a promise to keep. You and I have a lot of catching up to do.